# How to add plotline on highcharts with angle?

Tags: highcharts

I want to display line on linear chart like this:

[image]

It is plotline with angle.

How do I add plotline on highcharts with angle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Highcharts.SVGRenderer` class to add the line:

```
chart: {
    events: {
        load: function() {
            this.renderer.path(['M', 100, 50, 'L', 200, 300])
                .attr({
                    'stroke-width': 2,
                    stroke: 'red'
                })
                .add();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/u0hntrp6/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#path

Comment: Hi @an d, Use `toPixels` (https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#toPixels) method: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/o9025Lnm/